# mysqli_query dies every time in INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql

- Every time i try to insert value in my mysql database from php script, the query fails.
- Here are my codes.

  ```
  if ( empty($_POST)) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Tricky, you must have left something empty. That is why you are now will be redirected to Main page. Try again ;)");
      window.location.href ="index.php"</script>';


  }else {
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
  $your_info = $_POST['your_info'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $feed_area = $_POST['feed_area'];
  $remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $type = $_POST['type'];   
   if(!empty($first_name) || !empty($last_name) || !empty($email_id) || !empty($your_info) || !empty($title) || !empty($feed_area) || !empty($type))
   {
      echo '<div id="header">
      <div id="middle_heading">Confirmed!!!</div></div>';
      $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'feed_update');
      $query = "INSERT INTO feed_info (id, first_name, last_name, email_id, your_info, title,type, feed_area, feed_date, remote_addr)" VALUES (0, '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_id', '$your_info', '$title', '$type', '$feed_area', NOW(), '$remote_addr')";
     mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
     or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('query error alert');</script>");   
     mysqli_close($dbc);
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href ="index.php"</script>';
     }else {
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       alert("Tricky, you must have left something empty. That is why you are now will be redirected to Main page. Try again ;)");
       window.location.href ="index.php"</script>';
        }
      }
      ?>
  ```

Note:

- the html is not php self form.
- I also installed wordpress in my database, is there any problem with it too ?

Comment: How does it fail?  Perhaps it produces an error that you could include in the question.  You should also edit the question and include the definition of `feed_info`.

Comment: i tried to see the error by `mysql_error()`. But, then that ass gave me another error about the `mysql_error()`.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: `mysql_error` is from the `mysql_` API, you're using the `mysqli_` API. You can't mix and match database APIs.

Comment: so you mean i should try `mysqli_error` or something else.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: thats the problem, see comment 1 and 2

Comment: @user3461086: yes, use `mysqli_error`.

Comment: no, i got the answer, use `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Given a free down vote for your answer

Comment: If you're using MySQLi; then, for the love of <insert deity here>, learn to use bind variables with prepared statements.... then you don't need to escape it, or even need to remember quotes around strings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the answer , my data needs to be escaped. Short and Sweet use `mysql_real_escape_string`

for ex.
`$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);`
 and i know you must be thinking, i use `mysqli` but, when i tried `mysqli_real_espace_string()` it shows error.

Sorry, for disturbing you people.

Comment: Or use PDO to avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: Are you playing around??? You have used mysqli But your are telling mysql_real_escape_string solved the issue ?? How can you mix mysql and mysqli

Comment: You don't even need to use PDO to escape that issue, MySQLi supports bind variables